# Update a XML file

Tags: android, xml

I have a file that I open and parse and some of the categories can be modified.  Im wondering how I can update the original Xml file with the new values.

Comment: I parse an xml file holding data that the user gets from a local folder or dropbox folder, and make it into an object.  Some of the variables in the object can be modified with new data.  I want to take that new data and replace the data in the original xml file located in the dropbox or the local folder.  I just need to know how to update the data for a specific tag in xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the XML file is a normal sequential file. If so, you could *try* to update just one tag, but it would be easier and safer just to rewrite the entire file.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, it is normal XML sequence but not XML format, if that makes sense.  It uses the normal open tag close tag format but isnt UTF-8 or anyother format.